# Add new object to json using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file with user information (login and password). How to add a new object to Json using js? (so that after loading the page it would be saved in Json) Is it possible at all? Nowhere can I find the answer. I can use only (javascript, jQuery, json)

json

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "login":"admin",
            "password":"1207"
        }
    ]
}
```

js

```
 $(function() {
        const getOb=$.getJSON('user.json');
        var obj = JSON.parse(getOb);
        obj['users'].push({"login":"Donald","password":"78"});
        getOb = JSON.stringify(obj);
      });
```

Comment: You don't.  You give the information to the backend, and let it handle the storage of the data.  Plain text user credentials should never be exposed to the client side.  And plain text credentials on the server side are a security no-no in the first place.

Comment: `obj['users'].login = "Donald"; obj['users'].password="78";`

Comment: @Taplar "How to add a new object to Json using js?" is the question. Not how data should be handled.

Comment: When you are talking about storage of security information, *it's always the question*  @CQSmooth  ignoring a security issue is never a good idea

Comment: @ControlAltDel: *"so that after loading the page it would be saved in Json"* sounds to me like the data should be persisted on the server side, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @ControlAltDel: Storing values in named properties on an array is generally a terrible idea (and, while allowed in JS, is forbidden in JSON).

Comment: @Taplar not enough information leads me to believe that he is ignoring a security issue. :/

Comment: @CQSmooth in what world is storage of credentials in plain text not a security issue?  Encryption of credentials is security 101

Comment: @Taplar How would I know that these are credentials? Because he is using 'password' and 'login'? file looks local to me buddy. ;)

Comment: `$.getJSON('user.json');`  not local

Comment: @Taplar Bottom line is that the answer isn't 'You don't'. Thats my point.

Comment: It is you don't.  Because frontend javascript does not not have the ability to update a json file on a server (it has to do so through web requests to the server).  And you don't because it's a **major** security issue with having plain text credentials on the client side.   *That* is the bottom line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are fetching data over HTTP.

If you want to save it back to the server, then you need to make an HTTP request to the server (typically a PUT or POST request), and then have server-side code (written in the language of your choice) accept the HTTP request and save the data.

Typically you would save the data to a database from which you generate the JSON on demand rather than using a plain file (which saves you from race conditions).

---

Note:

- Storing passwords in plain text is dangerous. Use a hashing algorithm.
- Sending your authentication data to the client and asking it to authenticate itself:

  - Leaks your authentication data to anyone trying to log in
  - Allows anyone to edit the JS in their browser and claim to have logged in successfully

Move to a server-side authentication system where you send your credentials to the server, and then server-side code checks if they are good and then returns a token (JWT is currently a popular way to do this) which can be used to prove you are logged in.